# Pass a string variable from bash script to root macro

Tags: c++, bash, function, root-framework

I am defining a variable in a bash script in order to use it when I call my macro with root, such as:

```
user = name
root 'macro.C('$user')'
```

When the macro is executed, I get:

```
Processing macro.C(name)...
Error: Symbol name is not defined in current scope  :0:
*** Interpreter error recovered ***
```

My macro is basically defined as

```
void macro(char* user[])
{
   //code
}
```

I think the problem might be in this last chunk of code. All I want to do is to have a string/char I can use in my macro. Any idea how to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to the ROOT framework, not the root user account, so I updated the tags.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not see that when writing the tags down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't perform variable expansion on strings in single quotes (`'`). Try with double quotes (`"`) instead:

```
root "macro.C(\"$user\")"
```

Edit: escaped the inner string in response to your comment.

Comment: I get the same error. The single quotes only work if I have an integer?

Comment: Then the problem is with "root". Whatever that may be. I've never heard of such a language.

Comment: It's basically a framework dedicated to physics but all the macros are written in c++ so just consider this macro as a c++ file.

Comment: In that case, use double quotes inside the string as well, because C++ strings are always double-quoted. Escape them like this to avoid breaking up the shell's idea of where the string ends: `\"`.

Comment: The bash variable in OP's example is outside the single quotes, so it will be expanded. You may be right about needing to add double-quotes for the string literal though.

Comment: @interjay Heh, yes, I totally misinterpreted OP's command as "attempt at single-quoted string inside single quotes" (despite the syntax highlighting) and arrived at the hopefully correct answer somewhat by accident :D

Comment: It seems to be working indeed :) Thank you very much for your help!